# How to return the nearest representable float number multiple of another float number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point

I've both the value and step numbers given in float, such as:

```
double step = 0.4;
double value = 47.7121;
```

I need to return, for each value and step pair I give, the nearest representable float number multiple of the step.

So here's some expected results:

```
step = 0.4;
value = 47.7121;
===> it must snap to 47.6
result = 47.60000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625

step = 0.1;
value = 47.9435;
===> it must snap to 47.9
result = 47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
```

I'm able to [do this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ff9b2294a6099a) only with rational numbers (not float), in this form:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

inline double SnapValue(double value, int numerator, int denominator) {
    return round(value * denominator / numerator) * numerator / denominator;
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);

    std::cout << "result: " << SnapValue(47.7121, 2, 5) << std::endl; // step = 0.4, value 47.7121
    std::cout << "result: " << SnapValue(47.9435, 1, 10) << std::endl; // step = 0.1, value 47.9435

    return 0;
}
```

But, as I said, I don't have any rational numbers to start with, only float. 
How would you do this?

Comment: Convert the floating point number to a rational number?  You would have to limit yourself to a certain amount of precision since `.1` is actually `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

Comment: Mark, do you take into account the fact that the numbers `0.4` and `0.1` themselves can't be accurately represented using the `double` type? It seems that you missed this important point and thus are not satisfied with valid results.

Comment: @NathanOliver: not sure if I need to use rational number, maybe there's another way using only floats? That's why I ask :)

Comment: @SergGr: of course I know, and I'm aware of this. I'm not asking this. I can deal with the approx of the nearest representable value, but it must be that one, not another one :)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter may be able to help you

Comment: Then I probably don't understand from your question where do you see a problem with the literal translation of your code: `round(value / step)*step`?

Comment: Either the desired number is representable or it isn't. Can you decide which one you want? ;)

Comment: @SergGr: try yourself :) If you use that function, in the second case, it will return `47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`, not `47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375` (which is the nearest representable value)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: but I need the nearest representable one (as shown in the example) :)

Comment: @markzzz I'm not a floating point expert but my intuition says you need rational numbers to get what you want. Since the steps you want to use are not exactly representable there error will introduce error into your calculation and as you can see from your couple posts related to this, it is very hard to deal with it.

Comment: Mark, I think you need to start with the definition of  the "_multiple of the step_" such that it would say that `47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375` is a "multiply of `0.1`'s **_actual double representation_**"

Comment: @SergGr: `47.9` is multiple of `0.1`, right? I need the nearest representable float value of `47.9`, which is `47.899999999999998578914528479799628257751464843759` (not `47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`).

Comment: @SergGr: again :) I got that 0.1 can't be accurately represented as a double value. But I need to "treat" it as it is!!! So, once I read the value 0.1 from a JSON, even if its `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` I need to consider it as `0.1`, so with `47.9435` (which is `47.943500000000000227373675443232059478759765625`) I need to return `47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375` (which represent the nearest representable value with "hypothetical" step and value considered without floating error).

Comment: @markzzz If you are getting the value from a JSON can you get the value as a string instead of a `double`?  If so then you can easily convert the string into a rational number with no loss of precision which means you son't lose any precision in your snap function.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I get not only from JSON (was an example); it can come from different sources. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: @markzzz: How is it possible to “treat” .1 as representable even though it is not? If there is a routine `void double foo(double x)` and you pass 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 for `x`, how could `foo` know that you wanted .1 and not 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625? It has only the value it is given? If you want to work with .1 instead, you **must** define some way of expressing that. You could pass it as a string numeral, represent it as a rational fraction of 1/10, or use other methods. But you have to specify something.

Comment: To re-state what Eric says, if you can't represent `0.1` exactly how do you distinguish the case when you got `0.100...` and the user meant `0.1` and you got `0.100...` and the user did mean exactly `0.100...`? I'd say that the only real solution is to use some data type that can represent all the values you need exactly. Nathan's idea of parsing values into exact rationals is one of such approaches. Another approach might be using some fixed of floating point **_decimal_** (as opposed to binary) numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: "or use other methods" is the reason way I opened this question. How would you do it properly? Or its simple not achievable?

Comment: @markzzz: You need to change the question. Actually, you likely need to abandon this one and enter a new question. The title of this one asks about a “multiple of another **float** number”. It starts “I've both the value and step numbers **given in float**.” And it ends “But, as I said, I don't have any rational numbers to start with, **only float**.” So you have told us repeatedly that you have only a floating-point number. If you want to find the floating-point number that is nearest a multiple of an arbitrary rational number, you need to enter a new question asking that.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I see, thanks. English is not my naive english, that's why it could be a bit enigmatic.

Comment: `return value - remainder(value, step);`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

Your fist example:

```
    double step = 0.4;
    (float) (((int) (47.7121d / step + step / 2)) * step);

    -> 47.6
```

Your second example:

```
    double step = 0.1;
    (float) (((int) (47.9435d / step + step / 2)) * step);

    -> 47.9
```

This part is needed to get the nearest: `+ step / 2`.

Comment: This is not "snapping" to the value the OP wants in the second case: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05117caaa124a0ca

Comment: @MrSmith42: the version of 0.1 won't snap corectly, it goes to `47.90000000000000568434188608080148696899`

Comment: @markzzz: so you expect for not exact representation of 0.1 and 0.4 and limited and the limited accuracy of float arithmetic the result that you would get with infinite precision of 0.1 and 0.4 and infinite accurate arithmetic operations only rounded the result at the end?

Comment: @MrSmith42: `47.9` is multiple of `0.1`, right? I need the nearest representable float value of `47.9`, which is `47.899999999999998578914528479799628257751464843759` (not `47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`).

Comment: @markzzz: you are correct in real numbers, but 0.1 is a float and also 47.9 is a float. And in this case 0.1 is not an exact multiple of 47.9 .

Comment: @MrSmith42: I know. But I need to "treat" is as real number, even if they aren't (and use them, since I have only them, not real numbers and/or rational ones)

Comment: @markzzz: If possible void inexact arithmetic. Depending on the rest of your program you may be able to store the value in an `int` for the multiple of the `step` and save the inexact conversion to `float` until the value leaves your program (e.g. at the output). This way you avoid rounding errors as long as possible. (Like it is most times done with money when you store the cent-value in an `int` (instead of in a `float` that represents the fraction of a dollar).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, using [`std::round`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/):

```
#include <cmath>
double nearest_step(double value, double step)
{
    return std::round(value/step)*step;
}
```

Be aware that there is no floating point number with (exactly) the value `0.1`. The closest `double` to `1./10` is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, i.e., you will get slightly bigger numbers than expected most of the time. (Also, the result of the division is usually not exact, so in a few corner cases it may get rounded to the wrong direction.)

Comment: It doesn't works. Try `nearest_step(47.9435, 0.1)`. which should snap to 47.9 (which is `47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`): it outputs `47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`, which is different

Comment: @markzzz But you did not actually pass `0.1` (which is not a valid `double`), but `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. So the result is correct. Be more clear on how you want to pass the actual step-size if you want a better solution.

Comment: Its "what I have". I need to "treat" `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` as 0.1. That's the whole point of the question hehe

Comment: It's not what I read into "the nearest representable float number multiple [desired result] of another float number [step]". Maybe your question should be "how to find a rational [e.g. 1/10] close to a given float number [e.g. `0.100...55511..`]?"

Comment: yes, it could be! ;) Anyway, what I need its the same hehe

Comment: It _could_ be, but what if someone passes `sqrt(2.0)` or `M_PI` as stepsize? Do you expect the method to magically know what the user meant? And what if the user actually wants `3602879701896397/36028797018963968` and not `1/10`?

Comment: Correct note! Let say so that I'm ok with step that can be expressed correctly with rational numbers... how would you do this?

Comment: `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 == 3602879701896397/36028797018963968` **is** a rational number. In fact, every `double` (except `NaN` and +-`Inf`) can be expressed as a rational number.